# how to sum up a list of timestamps by the speaker name

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, datetime, time

i am working on a project
and i have extracted data from lists and have now 3 lists:

list 1 - a list of speaker names

```
['<M1>', '<M1>', '<M1>', '<M1>', '<M1>', '<M2>', '<M2>', '<M2>', '<M1>', '<M1>', '<M2>', '<M1>', '<M2>', '<M2>', '<M2>', '<M2>', '<M2>']
```

list 2 - a list of the beginning of talk time stamps

```
['[00:00:00.000]', '[00:00:08.010]', '[00:00:16.890]', '[00:00:26.210]', '[00:00:39.980]', '[00:00:48.100]', '[00:00:56.770]', '[00:01:08.010]', '[00:01:21.120]', '[00:01:46.130]', '[00:01:47.180]', '[00:01:49.390]', '[00:01:50.670]', '[00:02:02.320]', '[00:02:16.010]', '[00:02:21.110]', '[00:02:27.610]']
```

list 3 - a list of the ending of talk time stamps

```
['[00:00:08.010]', '[00:00:16.290]', '[00:00:26.210]', '[00:00:39.980]', '[00:00:48.100]', '[00:00:56.770]', '[00:01:08.010]', '[00:01:20.250]', '[00:01:33.850]', '[00:01:47.150]', '[00:01:49.370]', '[00:01:50.140]', '[00:02:01.350]', '[00:02:16.010]', '[00:02:20.150]', '[00:02:27.610]', '[00:02:39.040]']
```

what I need to do is whenever a single speaker talked many times (for example the first 5 elements of the list)
I need change the first ending segment [00:00:08.010] to [00:00:48.100] and get rid of all the entries in between (turn the 5 entries where there was a single talker to 1 entry)
and do this again for all speakers in the list.
if the speaker talked only once so it needs to stay the same.
can someone please help me and find a way of how to do this in python? 
thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
speakerOrder    = ['<M1>', '<M1>', '<M1>', '<M1>', '<M1>', '<M2>', '<M2>', '<M2>', '<M1>', '<M1>', '<M2>', '<M1>', '<M2>', '<M2>', '<M2>', '<M2>', '<M2>']
speakerBegin    = ['[00:00:00.000]', '[00:00:08.010]', '[00:00:16.890]', '[00:00:26.210]', '[00:00:39.980]', '[00:00:48.100]', '[00:00:56.770]', '[00:01:08.010]', '[00:01:21.120]', '[00:01:46.130]', '[00:01:47.180]', '[00:01:49.390]', '[00:01:50.670]', '[00:02:02.320]', '[00:02:16.010]', '[00:02:21.110]', '[00:02:27.610]']
speakerEnd      = ['[00:00:08.010]', '[00:00:16.290]', '[00:00:26.210]', '[00:00:39.980]', '[00:00:48.100]', '[00:00:56.770]', '[00:01:08.010]', '[00:01:20.250]', '[00:01:33.850]', '[00:01:47.150]', '[00:01:49.370]', '[00:01:50.140]', '[00:02:01.350]', '[00:02:16.010]', '[00:02:20.150]', '[00:02:27.610]', '[00:02:39.040]']


newSpeakerOrder = []
newSpeakerBegin = []
newSpeakerEnd   = []

currentSpeaker = None
for speakerIndex in range(len(speakerOrder)):
    speaker = speakerOrder[speakerIndex]
    if(currentSpeaker!=speaker):
        #If someone was already speaking add the time it ended
        if(currentSpeaker!=None):
            newSpeakerEnd.append(speakerEnd[speakerIndex-1])
        #Add the new Speaker
        newSpeakerOrder.append(speaker)
        currentSpeaker = speaker
        #Add the time it began
        newSpeakerBegin.append(speakerBegin[speakerIndex])

#Add the final time the last person stopped speaking
newSpeakerEnd.append(speakerEnd[-1])

print(newSpeakerOrder)
print(newSpeakerBegin)
print(newSpeakerEnd)
```

This is a solution I came up with, while not perfect it should solve your problem.
Just make sure beforehand that the original arrays have the same length.

Comment: Thank you soo much! I am a kinda beginner in python and after reviewing your code a couple of times you have thought me about an iteration way i did not know, i tried to use rangelen but not with a None value to hold the speakers each time

Comment: I'm glad it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [groupby function in itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html),Try this

```
from itertools import groupby

l1 = ['<M1>', '<M1>', '<M1>', '<M1>', '<M1>', '<M2>', '<M2>', '<M2>', '<M1>', '<M1>', '<M2>', '<M1>', '<M2>', '<M2>', '<M2>', '<M2>', '<M2>']
l2= ['[00:00:00.000]', '[00:00:08.010]', '[00:00:16.890]', '[00:00:26.210]', '[00:00:39.980]', '[00:00:48.100]', '[00:00:56.770]', '[00:01:08.010]', '[00:01:21.120]', '[00:01:46.130]', '[00:01:47.180]', '[00:01:49.390]', '[00:01:50.670]', '[00:02:02.320]', '[00:02:16.010]', '[00:02:21.110]', '[00:02:27.610]']
l3 = ['[00:00:08.010]', '[00:00:16.290]', '[00:00:26.210]', '[00:00:39.980]', '[00:00:48.100]', '[00:00:56.770]', '[00:01:08.010]', '[00:01:20.250]', '[00:01:33.850]', '[00:01:47.150]', '[00:01:49.370]', '[00:01:50.140]', '[00:02:01.350]', '[00:02:16.010]', '[00:02:20.150]', '[00:02:27.610]', '[00:02:39.040]'] 
start_index = 0
for (m,g) in groupby(l1):
    end_index = start_index + len(list(g)) -1
    start_time = l2[start_index]
    end_time = l3[end_index]
    start_index=end_index+1
    print(start_time)
    print(end_time)
    print("============")
```

output

```
[00:00:00.000]
[00:00:48.100]
============
[00:00:48.100]
[00:01:20.250]
============
[00:01:21.120]
[00:01:47.150]
============
[00:01:47.180]
[00:01:49.370]
============
[00:01:49.390]
[00:01:50.140]
============
[00:01:50.670]
[00:02:39.040]
============
```